# AngularJS compile a template and use it in Showdown extension

Tags: angularjs, showdown

I'm attempting to create a Showdown extension in my Angular app which will show scope variables. I was able to get it setup to show basic scope variables easily enough, but now I'd like to get it to where I can use the results of an `ng-repeat` and I can't get anything other than `[[object HTMLUListElement]]` to show.

Here's my controller so far:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', '$compile', function($scope, $window, $compile){
    $scope.machines = [
        { abbv: 'DNS', name: 'Did Not Supply' },
        { abbv: 'TDK', name: 'The Dark Knight' },
        { abbv: 'NGG', name: 'No Good Gofers'}
    ];
    $scope.machine = $scope.machines[0];

    $scope.machine_list = $compile('<ul><li ng-repeat="m in machines">{{m.abbv}}: {{m.name}}</li></ul>')($scope);
  $scope.md = "{{ machine_list }}";

    var scopevars = function(converter) {
        return [
            { type: 'lang', regex: '{{(.+?)}}', replace: function(match, scope_var){
                scope_var = scope_var.trim();

                return $scope.$eval(scope_var);
            }}
        ];
    };
    // Client-side export
    $window.Showdown.extensions.scopevars = scopevars;
}]);
```

Plunkr: [code so far](http://plnkr.co/edit/QZ8dAZsFD5AIQax7Oaqg?p=preview)

I feel like I've got to be close, but now I don't know if I'm on the completely wrong track for this, or if it's a showdown thing or an angular thing or what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I was fighting Angular (and losing quiet badly) with the way I was doing that. DOM in a controller is a no-no. And now I'm kind of angry about how easy it is once I started thinking properly and looking at the directive.

Now instead of trying to do the compile and everything within the controller, I included the `$compile` service in the directive I'm using, so:

```
htmlText = converter.makeHtml(val);
element.html(htmlText);
```

became:

```
htmlText = converter.makeHtml(val);
element.html(htmlText);
$compile(element.contents())(scope);
```

With that change in place I no longer need the portion of the extension that just did the basic evaluation, since it's being compiled `{{ machine.name }}` is automatically converted.

But that still left me not being able to specify a variable to insert a template, just variables. But now that the output is going to be compiled through angular I can put the template in a partial and use an extension to convert from a pattern to an `ng-include` which works.

New Controller Code:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', '$compile', function($scope, $window, $compile){
    $scope.machines = [
        { abbv: 'DNS', name: 'Did Not Supply' },
        { abbv: 'TDK', name: 'The Dark Knight' },
        { abbv: 'NGG', name: 'No Good Gofers'},
        { abbv: 'TotAN', name:'Tales of the Arabian Nights'}
    ];
    $scope.machine = $scope.machines[0];

  $scope.tpls = {
    'machinelist': 'partials/ml.html'
  };
  $scope.md = "{{machines.length}}\n\n{{include machinelist}}";

    var scopevars = function(converter) {
        return [
          { type: 'lang', regex: '{{include(.+?)}}', replace: function(match, val){
            val = val.trim();
            if($scope.tpls[val] !== undefined){
              return '<ng-include src="\''+$scope.tpls[val]+'\'"></ng-include>';
            } else {
              return '<pre class="no-tpl">no tpl named '+val+'</pre>';
            }
          }}
        ];
    };
    // Client-side export
    $window.Showdown.extensions.scopevars = scopevars;
}]);
```

And of course [the new plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/QZ8dAZsFD5AIQax7Oaqg?p=preview)

Hope this can help someone later down the road

[image: wisdom of the ancients]

Comment: showdown now has a [built directive](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown/blob/master/src/ng-showdown.js) that is going to be offered as a [standalone extension](https://github.com/showdownjs/angular)